# Java Optional, delete value and return, is there a better way?

Tags: java

```
public Optional<ReligiousOrderEntity> deleteReligiousOrderEntity( Long id){
    religiousOrderRepository.findById(id)
        .ifPresent( religiousOrderRepository::delete );
    
    return religiousOrderRepository.findById(id);
}
```

That is my code but I don't feel good about it. Looks to me that there should be a better way using Optionals.

The religiousOrderRepository.findById(id) returns an Optional with a
ReligiousOrderEntity on it, but before returning, we need to delete it.

(don't worry about the delete function, you can assume it works)

Comment: Your method won't work. If you find an entry, you delete it, then you try to find something again for the return value. That will always be an empty Optional because of the deletion.

Comment: You are right, so that means I need to find it, save it, delete it and then return the copy? Isn't there anything better with optionals?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? It is short, conside and specifies the logic you want. There is no built-in thing like `ifPresentThenDoThisAndReturnTheValue()` in `Optional`.

Comment: @f1sh It really depends on the semantics of their repository. If `delete` is a soft delete then it could work. You're likely right, but it's an overstatement to use words like "always". Of course, even if did work, it's inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find an entry, you delete it, then you try to find something again for the return value. That will always be an empty Optional because of the deletion.

You need to remember the value returned by the first `findById`:

```
public Optional<ReligiousOrderEntity> deleteReligiousOrderEntity(Long id){
    Optional<ReligiousOrderEntity> opt = religiousOrderRepository.findById(id)
    opt.ifPresent(religiousOrderRepository::delete);
    return opt;
}
```